# mix usage of AND operator and OR javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
{Object.keys(groupByMonthApplicants).map((obj,i) => 
    <div key={obj} style={(i > 0 && (this.state.selectedTabId !== 'rejected' || this.state.selectedTabId !== 'approved')) ? {paddingTop:'15px',background:'#eee'} : {}}>
    </div>)
}
```

I have selectedTabId not equal to rejected and approved I'm still seeing my div got padding, is my above expression wrong? I'm using OR in a bracket, so I expect "only apply padding-top if the selectedTabId is not on "rejected" or "approved" and `i` is more than one.

Comment: Don't forget that you can use some curly braces and an `if` statement inside your `map`. Remember that one day you'll have to read that and change it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is always true since `selectedTabId` if is equal to  `rejected` can't be equal to `approved`.

Use this

```
{Object.keys(groupByMonthApplicants).map((obj,i) => 
    <div key={obj} style={(i > 0 && !(this.state.selectedTabId === 'rejected' || this.state.selectedTabId === 'approved')) ? {paddingTop:'15px',background:'#eee'} : {}}>
    </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression is always `true` because `this.state.selectedTabId` can't be both `rejected` and `approved`:

```
this.state.selectedTabId !== 'rejected' || this.state.selectedTabId !== 'approved'
```